# Objetos FK a PK compuesta

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, mariadb

Hola como les va a todos?

Bueno estoy intentando crear una tabla automóviles, que cada automóvil tiene su marca y su modelo.

```
create table Marcas
(
    ID int primary key not null identity(1,1),
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    estado bit not null
)

go

create table Modelos
(
    ID int not null identity(1,1),
    IDMarca int foreign key references Marcas(ID),
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    primary key(ID, IDMarca)
)

go

create table Automoviles
(
    IDMarca int not null,
    IDModelo int not null,
    patente varchar(8) not null,
    foreign key (IDMarca, IDModelo) references Modelos(ID, IDMarca),
    primary key(IDMarca, IDModelo, patente)
)
```

Pero me esta generando un motón de errores al querer generar una clave foreanea de una tabla que tiene una clave primaria compuesta y la pregunta es como puedo generar una clave foranea de una tabla que tiene PK compuesta??

Comment: Hola, por favor indica con las etiquetas cual es el motor de base que usas, ya que asi es mas facil poderte dar una respuesta acertada

Comment: Porfavor, indica que error te genera para que los usuarios puedan ayudarte correctamente!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo acomode tal cual tu codigo en mi BD (Sql Server 2019) y ejecuto sin problemas, por favor indica cual es el error que te sale, y lo ejecute en el siguiente orden

```
create table Marcas
(
    ID int primary key not null identity(1,1),
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    estado bit not null
)



create table Modelos
(
    ID int not null identity(1,1),
    IDMarca int foreign key references Marcas(ID),
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    primary key(ID, IDMarca)
)



create table Automoviles
(
    IDMarca int not null,
    IDModelo int not null,
    patente varchar(8) not null,
    foreign key (IDMarca, IDModelo) references Modelos(ID, IDMarca),
    primary key(IDMarca, IDModelo, patente)
)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si es verdad disculpa es que renegué tanto que ya no me tenia fe jaajaja
Disculpa y muchas gracias ..!

Comment: No pasa nada! estamos es para ayudar